# Docker image based on Playwright image runs on my Mac but don't run on Ubuntu server

Tags: bash, docker, ubuntu, dockerfile, playwright

When I run this image om my Mac with M1 chip, everything is OK.
But when I try to run on server with Ubuntu, container stops with error "**exec /bin/sh: exec format error**"

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/playwright:v1.18.1-arm64
RUN apt-get -y update && apt-get -y upgrade
ADD build/libs/program.jar /tmp
WORKDIR /tmp
RUN apt-get -y install openjdk-11-jre-headless && apt-get clean;
CMD java -jar program.jar
```

This error displays on each first command RUN. Even if the command is like "RUN ls -la", I will get ***"/bin/sh -c ls -la returned a non-zero code: 1".***

I tried to change SHELL["bin/bash","-c"] and image version but there was no effect.

If I use "FROM ubuntu", commands work, but I need exactly image for Playwright with browser dependencies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are building an image with ARM architecture (check with `docker inspect <your_image> | grep "Archi"`). This image cannot be executed on another architecture (probably `amd64` for your Ubuntu server).

You should:

- use an `amd64` base image (`mcr.microsoft.com/playwright:v1.18.1-arm64` => `mcr.microsoft.com/playwright:v1.18.1-focal` for example)
- build your image with `docker build --platform linux/amd64`